# Secure config for Apache2.4 + PHP-FPM?

Tags: apache2, php, apache2-module

Very rusty with PHP and Apache so hopefully this will be an easy question.  The Apache Wiki has [a page](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM) on setting up PHP-FPM with Apache 2.4, but the specified `ProxyPassMatch` method of forwarding requests for .php files to the php-fpm module is insecure.  Is there a standard/canonical setup that is secure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not insecure anymore. There's a new config parameter for php-fpm (since 5.3.9), 
security.limit_extensions, that defaults to '.php' so php-fpm will only run files with these extensions. It won't run the .jpg in that example.